# Different compilers showing different results for sizeof() operator

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, mingw

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned const* const a, b;
    printf("size of a: %ld, size of b: %ld ", sizeof(a), sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives different outputs on different compilers.
In gcc compiler, the output is:

> "size of a: 8, size of b: 4

In MSVS 2019 compiler and MinGW compiler, the output is

> "size of a: 4, size of b: 4

I am looking for an explanation behind this behavior.

Edit:

Do *a* and *b* have different variable types here?

Comment: `a` is a pointer, `b` is not

Comment: The `*` binds to the variable, not the type, which is why many prefer to write it as `int *a, b;` instead. Or even better keep them separate `int *a;`, `int b;` and avoid all possible confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration

```
unsigned const* const a, b;
```

is parsed as

```
unsigned const (* const a), b;
```

Thus, `a` and `b` have different types - `a` is a `const` pointer to `const unsigned int`, while `b` is just a `const unsigned int`.

This is an aspect of C declaration syntax that isn't well-taught and constantly trips people up.  Declarations are split into two main parts - a sequence of *declaration specifiers* and a sequence of *declarators*.  Pointer-ness, array-ness, and function-ness are specified as part of the declarator.  For array and function declarators it's obvious because the `[]` and `()` operators are postfix, but for pointers it's confusing because a) the `*` operator is unary, not postfix, and b) whitespace isn't meaningful - `T *p` and `T* p` are both interpreted the same way, as `T (*p)`.

For the declaration above, the declaration specifiers are `unsigned const` and the declarators are `* const a` and `b`.

C does not specify exact sizes for most types - instead, it specifies a minimum range of values those types must be able to represent.  An `unsigned int` must be able to represent values in *at least* the range `[0..65535]`, meaning it must be *at least* 16 bits wide, but it may be wider.  Pointer types are as big as the architecture needs them to be, typically 8 bytes on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

On 32 bit program pointers are 32 bit long == 4 bytes. 64 bits build will have 64 bits long pointers - thus 8 bytes.

sizeof of `int` is minimum 2 bytes - usually 4.

But even the same compiler can give you different numbers (if compiling 32 or 64 bits program):

[image]

https://godbolt.org/z/a45MPa

Comment: Do variables a and b have different types here?

Comment: `a` is pointer to `unsigned int `, `b` is `unsigned int `

Comment: @Shubhashish Yes, `a` is a (constant) pointer to (constant) unsigned int, but `b` is just (constant) unsigned int

Answer (score 0):

Although, 4 bytes integer size is typical, it is not guaranteed. In particular, sizes depend on the hardware and the compiler. The int size in different compilers can be either 2 bytes or 4 bytes.